# How to access elasticsearch nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to get my head wrapped around nested queries but I can't get this to work.
I have 2 items in ES that look like this

```
 {
"_index": "catalog",
"_type": "products",
"_source": {
   "product": {
      "ean": "abc",
      "features": {
         "Product Type": "DVD player",
      },
      "color": "Black",
      "manufacturer": "Sony",
      "sitedetails": [
         {
            "name": "amazon.com",
            "sku": "zzz",
            "url": "http://www.amazon.com/dp/zzz"
         }
      ],
      "category": "Portable DVD Players"
   }
 }
},
{
"_index": "catalog",
"_type": "products",
"_source": {
   "product": {
      "ean": "def",
      "features": {
         "Product Type": "MP3 player",
      },
      "color": "Black",
      "manufacturer": "LG",
      "sitedetails": [
         {
            "name": "amazon.com",
            "sku": "aaa",
            "url": "http://www.amazon.com/dp/aaa"
         }
      ],
      "category": "MP3 Players"
   }
}
```

}

2 questions:

What is the curl to get sku = zzz?

What is the curl to get both items on a search for "players"?

tnx!

Comment: Share the mapping please `GET /index/type/_mapping`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyy bro, lets do the magic.
First , you need an mapping including your nested objects, like this

```
curl -XPUT "http://192.168.99.100:9200/catalog" -d'
{
      "mappings": {
         "products": {
            "properties": {
               "product": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                      "features": {
                        "type":"nested"  
                      },
                     "sitedetails": {
                        "type": "nested"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
   }
}'
```

After that, lets insert your data (change your Product Type to product_type)

```
 curl -XPOST "http://192.168.99.100:9200/catalog/products" -d'
{
    "product": {
      "ean": "abc",
      "features": {
         "product_type": "DVD player"
      },
      "color": "Black",
      "manufacturer": "Sony",
      "sitedetails": [
         {
            "name": "amazon.com",
            "sku": "zzz",
            "url": "http://www.amazon.com/dp/zzz"
         }
      ],
      "category": "Portable DVD Players"
   }
}'
```

Now, lets do the query

```
curl -XPOST "http://192.168.99.100:9200/catalog/products/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "product.features",
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "product.features.product_type": "player"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "product.sitedetails",
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "product.sitedetails.sku": "zzz"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```

And the response will be:

```
  "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.4054651,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "catalog",
            "_type": "products",
            "_id": "AVM_fcYgvVoSi3OfqPTX",
            "_score": 1.4054651,
            "_source": {
               "product": {
                  "ean": "abc",
                  "features": {
                     "Product Type": "DVD player"
                  },
                  "color": "Black",
                  "manufacturer": "Sony",
                  "sitedetails": [
                     {
                        "name": "amazon.com",
                        "sku": "zzz",
                        "url": "http://www.amazon.com/dp/zzz"
                     }
                  ],
                  "category": "Portable DVD Players"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

Hope it help :D

Answer (score -2):

Use:

1. `curl 'http://localhost:9200/catalog/products/_search?q=sku:"zzz"&pretty=true'`
2. `curl 'http://localhost:9200/catalog/products/_search?q=sku:*&pretty=true'`. like my thinking, you want to get data within sku:"zzz" and sku:"aaa".

Referer: 
http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/

http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/elasticsearch-in-5-minutes.html